# Isometry groups of round three manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

I'm interested in isometry groups of round 3 manifolds, especially Riemannian homogeneous ones.

Here are my thoughts so far:

- The round three sphere $ S^3 $ has isometry group $ O_4 $.
- Round projective space is the sphere mod the antipodal isometry (which is a rotation for odd spheres)
  $$
  \mathbb{R}P^3 \cong S^3/-I
  $$
  Using the normalizer formula for the isometry group of a quotient of a simply connected manifold we have
  $$
  \text{Iso}(\mathbb{R}P^3)\cong N_{\text{Iso}(S^3)}(-I)/-I=O_4/-I 
  $$
  which further simplifies as
  $$
   \text{Iso}(\mathbb{R}P^3) \cong (O_1 \ltimes SO_4)/-I \cong O_1 \ltimes (SO_4/-I) \cong O_1 \ltimes (SO_3 \times SO_3)
  $$
- For a homogeneous lens space $ L_{p,1} \cong SU_2/C_p $ where $ C_p $ is $ p $ element cyclic subgroup the normalizer of $ C_p $ in $ SO_3 $ (or $ SU_2 $) is $ O_2 $ and $ O_2/C_p  \cong O_2 $. So I think the isometry group should be something like
  $$
  O_2 \times O_3
  $$
- Another reason I'm guessing $ \text{Iso}(L_{p,1}) \cong O_3 \times O_2 $ is that from the Hopf fibration
  $$
  S^1 \to S^3 \to S^2
  $$
  we can mod out by $ C_p $
  $$
  S^1/C_p \to S^3/C_p \to S^2
  $$
  So we have
  $$
  S^1 \to L_{p,1} \to S^2
  $$
  and then I am just taking the the direct product of the isometry group of the fiber and of the base. (I know you can't generally do that for nontrivial fiber bundles for example no metric on the Klein bottle has isometries $ O_2 \times O_2 $ but just noting here that it sort of agrees with my earlier guess from the normalizer perspective).
- The normalizers of other groups are $ D_{2n} \trianglelefteq D_{4n} $ for $ n \geq 3 $, $ D_{4} \cong C_2 \times C_2 \trianglelefteq S_4 $, $ A_4 \trianglelefteq S_4 $, $ A_5 \trianglelefteq A_5 $. The point is that all other discrete subgroups of $ SO_3 $ (and $ SU_2 $) have discrete normalizer with finite index. So for the homogeneous prism manifolds and three exceptional manifolds $ SU_2/ \Gamma $ I think roughly the normalizer of $ \Gamma $ is $ \Gamma \times SU_2 $ so the isometry group is roughly $ (SU_2 \times \Gamma) /\Gamma $ or rather
  $$
  \text{Iso}(SU_2/\Gamma) \cong SU_2 \rtimes O_1 
  $$
  to include orientation reversing isometries
- For round three manifolds that are not homogeneous I think they probably all have isometry group $ O_2 $ (just a guess)

Comment: When you say round, do you mean smooth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The isometry groups of elliptic $3$-manifolds were computed by McCullough in

> Isometries of Elliptic 3-Manifolds.  Journal of the London Mathematical Society, Volume 65, Issue 1, February 2002, Pages 167–182

which can be found on the [arxiv here.](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0010077)

(Community wiki because McCullough did all the work.)

Comment: For the isometry group of $ L_{2m+1,1} $, $ m\geq 1$, which the author writes as $ O_2^* \tilde{\times} S^3 \cong (O_2^* \times SU_2)/(-1,-1)  $ there are two connected components as indicated in table 3. As for the connected component of the identity is it clear to you if it is $ SO_2 \times SU_2 $ or $ SO_2 \times SO_3 $?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira: I believe it's $SO(2)\tilde{\times} SU(2)$, which is isomorphic to $U(2)$ (and is not isomorphic to either option you listed since $\pi_1(U(2))\cong \mathbb{Z}\not\cong \pi_1(SO(2)\times SO(3))$ and $Z(U(2))\cong \mathbb{Z}\not\cong Z(SO(2)\times SU(2))$)

Comment: Ah thank you. It's easy to forget that $ U_2 $ is not a direct product. As you say $ \pi_1(U_2) \cong \mathbb{Z} \ncong \mathbb{Z} \times C_2  \cong \pi_1(SO_2 \times SO_3) $ and $ Z(U_2) \cong SO_2 \ncong SO_2 \times C_2 \cong Z(SO_2 \times SU_2) $ (note slight typo computing the center in the previous comment). So they are all distinguished by counting elements of order 2.